# One big event based table OR multiple tables? Hive table design consideration

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hiveql, parquet

I am working on a problem where we have lot of different events coming from different sources and these events have 60% fields common. So, with that said, I initially started with created individual tables for each event and now see that there can many events and almost 60% data fields are same among these events, I am thinking of create one event table that will have columns for all events and I am going to add a type column in this table which will let my spark jobs pick events relevant to them. This table is a Hive external table, and spark jobs will load data into it by processing a staging json table.

I am seeking input from experts to see if this one table design is feasible?

1. My partition will be like partition(date string, customer type, eventType string)
2. I might have an extra partition of region, but haven't decided on that yet
3. The data is stored as Parquet format
4. A benefit I see is, when a new event is introduced I just have to add columns specific to it and extend my spark framework against adding a new table and stuff

My cluster has 6 DNs with 32Gig RAM on each and 5TB disk space each. Since spark is our core processing framework, I am worried about resource consumption for all the jobs that will run? What if partitions becomes too big? I am considering performance and speed too?

Any inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There a some things to consider before decide how store your data.

- Why use parquet instead of avro? there are some limitations in Hive around the evolution schema using parquet instead of avro.
- What kind of operations will you do over your data? if you will use a few columns, I would recommend use parquet instead of avro, but if that is not the case and will not be doing aggregations and you will be mostly working at row level, I would suggest avro
- What are you expecting to gain merging the tables? will you do operations using non-common fields between the different tables? is this a common case? From the usability perspective, maybe is a good idea keep all your tables independent from each other and create a table with the common fields, this will let  you to work with non-common columns if is required for those records without those columns and also with common fields from the "merged" table. , that is the good thing about external tables.
- how much will growth your data daily? this is a very important point, will you be generating a lot of small files? if that is the case, you should consider intermediates process to create your new files and make your files bigger to at least match with the block size, this is a important point considering the size of your cluster which is small.
- Take care about how you partition the data a very fine-grained could end in a lot of small files which will impact in your performance. do you really need partitions by customer and eventtype?
- I am not sure about the details around your spark framework but introduce new columns directly seem to be very hard to maintain, considerate use genericrecord if you decide use avro

I hope it helps with some decisions.

EDIT: answering some questions

Hive seems to have some limitations when you modify the column structure for parquet tables. For example, to modify the name of the columns in the table definition you have to use the flag parquet.column.index.access to make this work, this mean, that all your data will need contains the same schema. The replace columns in Hive to add a completely new definition is not working in the Hive version 1.3, for some reason, I cant read new columns, not sure if this is fix in other versions.

Additionally, the schema evolution in spark was turned off because it is more expensive, essentially you have to read all the files and consolidate the schema to work in this way and depending on your number of files, this can impact the performance

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. We will be doing grouping/ranking/avg etc on this table and parquet makes sense in that case. This table is intermediate and new tables which will have fraction of what this table has will be created in downstream process in pipeline. There is no element that define event uniqueness, so splitting them is tough and to add I am interested in common and specific fields. Having one table makes easy to add new events. We have date as partition as of now. What could be tough in spark if I introduce new columns? also can you comment on parquet limitation in hive?